# MonoTouch Battery Level Always -1

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, power-management, uidevice

I set `BatteryMonitoringEnabled` to True before accessing the battery information.

The documentation says that -1 should be returned only if the monitoring hasn't been enabled.

However, I always get -1 as the value of `BatteryLevel` property and Unknown as `BatteryState`, despite that I enabled the monitoring.

```
UIDevice.CurrentDevice.BatteryMonitoringEnabled=true;

Console.WriteLine (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.BatteryLevel.ToString());
```

Result -1

```
Console.WriteLine (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.BatteryState.ToString());
```

Result "Unknown"

Anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me. Could you be running this inside the iOS simulator ? If so what's you're observing would be normal results.

If you cannot this to work please fill a bug report @ http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and state which version of MonoTouch, devices, iOS versions are in use.

Comment: Yes, I was trying this in the emulator. I was under impression that it should work just like a normal device. Now I know it shouldn't :) Is there any list of things that don't work on the emulator?

Comment: Keep in mind it's a *simulator* not an *emulator* - that has pros and cons :-)